Formulation of Plateau‘s Problem
I am working with Michael Struwe’s book Variational Methods and focusing on the Plateau problem (page 19). He claims that a naive approach to solving the Plateau problem would be to minimize the following functional
$$A(u)=\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{\det(\nabla u^T\nabla u)}dz$$
among $u\in H^{1,2}\cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$.
Furthermore, he asserts that this functional $A$ is invariant under arbitrary changes of parameters. I now have two questions. How does he formulate the area functional, and how can one understand the invariance of the area functional?
Any hint is greatly appreciated!

First notice that $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is the function parameterizing the surface. From standard multivariable calculus, we know that
$$
A(u) = \int_\Omega \|u_x\times u_y\|~\mathrm{d}z,
$$
where $z = (x,y)^T\in\Omega$. However, recall that for two vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^3$, we have $$\|a\times b\|^2 + (a\cdot b)^2 = \|a\|^2\|b\|^2.$$ Rearranging and applying this to the vectors $a = u_x$ and $b=u_y$, we have
$$
A(u) = \int_\Omega \sqrt{\|u_x\|^2\|u_y\|^2-(u_x\cdot u_y)^2}~\mathrm{d}z.
$$
Recall that $\|a\|^2 = a\cdot a$, then notice that $\|u_x\|^2\|u_y\|^2-(u_x\cdot u_y)^2 = \det(G)$, where
$$
G=\begin{pmatrix}\|u_x\|^2 & u_x\cdot u_y \\ u_x\cdot u_y & \|u_y\|^2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}u_x\cdot u_x & u_x\cdot u_y \\ u_x\cdot u_y & u_y\cdot u_y\end{pmatrix} = \nabla u^T\nabla u.
$$
We then have
$$
A(u) = \int_{\Omega}\sqrt{\det(\nabla u^T\nabla u)}~\mathrm{d}z,
$$
as desired.
